# FileStream disable Close()

Tags: c#, filestream

I'm creating a temporary file with the `DeleteOnClose` option:

```
var fileStream = File.Create(Path.GetTempFileName(), 4096, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose);
```

Another class(which I cannot modify) will write some data to this file:

```
someObject.WriteDataToFile(fileStream);
```

then I want to retrieve the data for further processing, close the stream, and let the file be automatically deleted.

But `someObject.WriteDataToFile(fileStream)` also calls `fileStream.Close()`, which will delete the file, so I cannot retrieve its contents.

Question: How can I keep `fileStream` from being closed by the code in `someObject.WriteDataToFile()` ?

Comment: why not just delete your file manually after closing?

Comment: You can't modify that code, so don't create the file with DeleteOnClose

Comment: You could write a decorator around the filestream that implements 'Close' as empty method and does the base.Close() in it's dispose method.

Comment: I create a lot of these files, and some of them can get pretty big, so I'm using `DeleteOnClose` to avoid them not being deleted(in case of an error  or process terminated, etc.)

Comment: @Marvin Smit: good idea, post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the decorator pattern to solve this

e.g;

```
public class UnclosableFileStream : StreamDecorator
{
    public UnclosableFileStream(Stream original) : base(original)
    {

    }

    public override void Close()
    {

    }

    public void RealClose()
    {
        base.Close();
    }
}

public abstract class StreamDecorator : Stream
{
     .... implements Stream base case
}
```

This example uses a custom method. You could also consider implementing the IDisposable interface and call Close on Dispose()

Hope this helps,